# Is it possible to use Vagrant's NFS synching feature to mount VM's directories to local Windows machine?

Tags: windows, vagrant, nfs

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to mount some directories to my local machine. There are two issues:

1. The virtual machine is NOT created by "vagrant up"
2. OS on my local machine is Windows 10 Home.

So I cannot use Windows default NFS feature which is only packaged in Ultimate edition. I could not find other FREE reliable mounting tool working well from Windows. There are some SSH Fuse and NFS clones for Windows, but I had problems with all of them. The Vagrant's NFS synching feature is capable to do it exactly how I want it to be, but of course you have to create machine by Vagrant itself. So I had an idea to somehow abuse Vagrant's NFS just to mount directories, but with no success. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize SMB feature without vagrant to share folders between win host and ubuntu guest. It's using directory network sharing, but you have to use long commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

After many many hours I have turned my VM into exportable Vagrant box and then it worked. Unfortunately I don't remember all the things I had to do, but some I do remember.

1. I had to create user Vagrant, which is able to sudo without password, set him insecure vagrant key so Vagrant will be able to ssh and update the key (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant.pub)
2. Install some packages like (virtualbox-guest-utils, virtualbox-guest-dkms, nfs-common)
3. Adjust /etc/network/interfaces, so Vagrant is able to change it

And maybe some more. It was trial/error until Vagrant was able to bring VM machine to life. But I have to say after 2 months later I understood how NFS is working under Windows, and now I am able to mount via NFS without vagrant box as well. You need:

1. winnfsd.exe from Vagrants plugin vagrant-winnfsd, or you can compile it yourself from https://github.com/winnfsd/winnfsd)
2. Create file called "nfspaths" and put the paths you want to mount to your VM, like:

C:/var/www/project/app

3. Create nfsservice.bat with content:

START "" C:\path\to\winnfsd.exe -log off -pathFile "C:\path\to\nfspaths"

4. run nfsservice.bat
5. Log to your VM and mount via nfs (it is imporant to use upppercase drive letter!):
   sudo mount -o "vers=3,udp" 192.168.77.1:/C/var/www/project/app /var/www/project/develop/app/ver/init

And you don't need Vagrant anymore for mounting folders, which was my main goal.